# ARToolkit in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I'm beginner in Android Studio, I tried to build an AR application that I found `ARToolkit SDK` and downloaded it but I don't know how to use it and how to add it to Android Studio. There are some example projects in it that I couldn't open them with Android Studio too.

Comment: also my gradle cant sync in the example projects

Answer (score 1):

in the ARToolKit SDK there is a folder called 'android' that contains a ./build.sh and a ./build_native_examples.sh you need to execute the ./build.sh before trying to run the examples.

Follow the description here what you need to do in order to get the ./build.sh to work.
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_native

You should be able to 'import' the samples into AndroidStudio. But as said, first of all you need to follow the instructions and run ./build.sh

Tell me how it goes. I'm happy to support you further.

Comment: while running those shell scripts, am getting ndk-build not found. Do i have to keep this project inside sdk path?
Note: i'd execucted setenv script already.

Comment: Probably the wrong path to the Android ndk. Hava a second look at the documentation. You need to have several variables pointing to Android SDK and NDK

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I suggest you use this project: https://github.com/plattysoft/ArToolKitJpctBaseLib

It is a wrapper on top of ARToolKit that connects it with the 3D Engine jPCT-AE.

- You can use gradle to import the dependencies
- You can use ARToolKit directly if you chose so
- All the examples are built with Android Studio
- The creation of an AR app is more streamlined (no need to define a renderer)
- Having a 3D engine simplifies creating augmentations a lot

Comment: This isn't really an answer... an answer to "how do I get something to work?" isn't "do something else", even if it *is* helpful.

Comment: the answer starts with "as an alternative". In general I do not recommend to compile ARToolkit when there are binaries available.

Answer (score 0):

Just download this and import on Android Studio : File->New->Import project ...
fix Gradle (if asked )
[GitHub working example of ARToolKit](https://github.com/kosiara/artoolkit-android-studio-example)